# db_select when column name is a mysql keyword

Tags: php, mysql, drupal-7

Selecting using `db_select` and when database column happens to be a [reserved mysql word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/keywords.html) (`when` in this case) results in an error.

Table:

```
+-----------------------------------+------------+--------+
|               sort_id             |    when    |  user  |
+-----------------------------------+------------+--------+
| 1                                 | 1448270950 |    123 |
| 3                                 | 1448270955 |     12 |
| 50                                | 1448270959 |     45 |
+-----------------------------------+------------+--------+
```

Standard drupal7 select using `db_select`:

```
$query = db_select('naughty_table', 'd')
    ->fields('d', array('sort_id', 'when', 'user'))
    ->condition('user', $uid)
    ->limit($limit)
    ->execute();
```

Column named `when` is the problem here.

I know I can write the query using plain SQL:

```
db_query("SELECT sort_id, user, `when` FROM {naughty_table} WHERE user = :user", array(":user" => $user_id));
```

But there **should** be a way to solve this using regular db_select?

Comment: you should avoid using keywords as tablenames, but maybe it works if you try this: surround when with backticks `\``

Comment: Use backticks `\`` http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23129/benefits-of-using-backtick-in-mysql-queries

Comment: sure I always avoid when I create my own tables, but in this case this is what I have

Comment: @chris85, I'm sorry for this comment, but how did you format the backtick as code^^

Comment: @swidmann Escape the backtick with backslash. e.g. (this might get ugly) `\`\\`\``

Comment: Backticks do not seem to work

Comment: If Drupal's `db_select` doesn't back-tick the fields, or allow you to prefix them with the table name, you may have a problem : something like `SELECT naughty_table.when` or `SELECT \`naughty_table\`.\`when\`` *should* work...

Comment: Not too familiar with drupal but what error are you getting?

Comment: @chris85, thanks it worked :)

Comment: Alternatively use Drupal's `db_query()` and raw SQL if you have to? (sanitisation issues though maybe? - I'm not big on Drupal)

Comment: @CD001, yes, but it would be a pity to know that db_select cannot deal with such a widespread yet simple problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`where()` should be used instead instead:

```
$query = db_select('my_table', 'd')
  ->fields('d', array('sort_id', '`when`', 'user'))
  ->condition('user', '123')
  ->where('`when` = :timestamp', array(':timestamp' => 1448160590))
  ->execute();
```

Answer (score -1):

Your query should be something like:

```
$query = db_select('naughty_table', 'd')
    ->fields('d', array('`sort_id`', '`when`', '`user`'));
    ->condition('`user`', $uid)
    ->limit($limit)
    ->execute();
```

Pay attention to the backticks around the fields. In fact, phpMyAdmin always uses these backticks to avoid running into a reserved word issue.

Having said that, it's always a good idea to avoid having fields named as reserved words in your table (I know that you didn't create it, but just a note).

Comment: Are you sure db_select allows backticks?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but technically it should, since backticks are technically harmless.

Comment: OK, have you tried the addExpression method?  $query->addExpression('`user`', 'username'); . This thread is very helpful: https://www.drupal.org/node/1426084